# Show that $\|A\|_\infty \leq \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\|A\|_\infty \leq \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$ for any $m \times n$ matrices.

I know $\|A\|_\infty$ is the largest row sum of the matrix, but I'm not sure how to compare with $\|A\|_2$ especially since matrix 2-norm is induced by some other vector. All hints will be appreciated!

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957909/norm-equivalence-frobenius-and-infinity) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957909/norm-equivalence-frobenius-and-infinity/960554#960554)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?